# virt-sandbox-service creates sandbox without ip-address

Tags: ip-address, libvirt

I am trying to create and start a apache instance in sandbox, using the following commands on Fedora-19 (64-bit OS).

```
virt-sandbox-service create -C -N dhcp,source=default -s static,label=system_u:system_r:svirt_lxc_net_t:s0:c1,c2 -u httpd.service apache1

virt-sandbox-service start apache1
```

This creates and starts (apache) properly but, it does not get a ip-address on eth0, just has loop-back address. How to configure the sandbox network and connect to this apache instance to/from external network ?

**Info about my host system:**

```
#ifconfig virbr0
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:6c:ea:ed  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

#brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.5254006ceaed   yes     virbr0-nic

#virsh net-list
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes

#virsh net-dumpxml default
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>d507981a-cbd8-47c4-8ba1-fb20496a25a7</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0' />
  <mac address='52:54:00:6c:ea:ed'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254' />
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Note: I did not create this bridge. This is automatically created & configured by the Virtual Machine Manager.

**Info about the sandbox created:**

```
#virt-sandbox-service connect apache1
sh-4.2# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feaa:e2c3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:aa:e2:c3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 33  bytes 2232 (2.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 648 (648.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It seems that the bridge is only ipv4 configured and the sandbox is only ipv6 configured. Please can anyone tell how to either configure the bridge to ipv6 or configure sandbox to ipv4. I think it might solve my issue.

Comment: your `virbr0` has 0 packets transferred nor received. you can try to restart it via `virsh net-destroy default;virsh net-start default`

Comment: Same issue, on F19, everything is up to date as of 02/5/2014.